# Handle errors in release build

Tags: flutter

I build a Flutter app and I handled some exceptions, all exceptions were cached by the app in  debug mode but in release mode, I can't  cache any exceptions, it seems there is a handler in the flutter engine, I try a lot of exceptions handlers and nothing helped me

1. FlutterError.onError
2. catcher
3. PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError
4. etc..

Answer (score 0):

For Debugging, I would recommend using a generic try/catch block

```
try{

// do something
}
catch(e){
throw Exception(e);
}
```

and then run the app using --release flag and check the logs in console.